# Prolog - Exercise on facts and lists

Tags: database, prolog, fact, visual-prolog

The problem is that I need to program a predicate capable of consulting the products in a database so that it returns a list filled with the names of the products its prices are reduced(that is indicated by the "state".

```
domains
    state =  reduced ; normal
    element = string
    list = element*
database
    producte (string, integer, state)
predicates
    nondeterm reduced(list)
clauses 
   % ---> producte( description , price , state )
    producte("Enciam",2,reduced). 
producte("Peix",5,normal).
producte("Llet",1,reduced). 
producte("Formatge",5,normal).
    %unique case
    reduced([D]):-
         producte(D,_,reduced).
    %general case
    reduced([D|L]) :- 
         producte(D,_, reduced),retract(producte(D,_,reduced)),reduced(L).
Goal
    reduced(List).
```

I appreciate it.
Now, it gives me three different solutions. How could I force the predicate to give me one solution? In fact, The last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't use visual-prolog, I'll just propose something I [found in the doc](http://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Lists_and_Recursion#Finding_All_the_Solutions_at_Once).

```
reduced(List) :-
    List = [ Price || producte(_, Price, reduced) ].
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow you. I appreciate your interest. What do I do with that line you wrote.

Comment: that's the whole thing actually. Did you at least try to run that ? ><

Comment: Well, nein, cause' I'm using Visual Prolog and it doesn't allow this kind of structure. Although I've edited the code and now give 3 possibles solutions. I want just the last one because is the good one. What would you do to force it to give the last solution found? Thanks in advance

Comment: well I took this structure from the link posted that is a link of the Visual Prolog doc. If that doesn't help I'll stop there since I don't use Visual Prolog. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What about when the first product in the list is NOT reduced -- you have no rule for that case.

Comment: Sure: if the first element isn't reduced, then the result should just what you get by reducing the rest.  But now you have a new problem: what if the LAST element ISN'T reduced?

Comment: I have edit the code. Now it gives me 3 solutions. THe good one is the last one. How would you force the program to provide just the last one?

Comment: Write a predicate to handle just that case: the list is a single, unreduced element.  (Hint: It should be similar to your unique case, which handled the last item being reduced.)

Comment: Note that your solution is not 'returning' anything, but rather removing the fact that certain producte's are reduced.  The usual way this would be done would be to have reduced have 2 arguments: the list of items you are interested in, and that list with the reduced items removed (without altering the facts that allowed you to compute the list).